# How to cut third symbol from string and alert it without third symbol

Tags: javascript

How can i correctly cut out letter "v" and alert str without "v"

```
var str = "Javascript";
var cut = str.substring(2,3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = "Javascript";
var cut = str.substring(0,2) + str.substring(3);
alert(cut);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the right tool ([`String#substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)). You need *two* substrings that you put back together, the `"Ja"` and the `"ascript"`. So:

```js
var str = "Javascript";
var cut = str.substring(0, 2) + str.substring(3);
alert(cut);
```

Another option would be [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), which will replace the first occurrence of what you give it unless you tell it to do it globally with a regex and the `g` flag (which we won't, because we just want to remove that one `v`):

```js
var str = "Javascript";
var cut = str.replace("v", "");
alert(cut);
```

---

Just for fun, there is another way, but it's a bit silly: You can split the string into an array of single-character strings, remove the third entry from the array, and then join it back together:

```js
var str = "Javascript";
var cut = str.split("").filter(function(_, index) {
  return index != 2;
}).join("");
alert(cut);
```

or

```js
var str = "Javascript";
var cut = str.split("");
cut.splice(2, 1); // Delete 1 entry at index 2
cut = cut.join("");
alert(cut);
```

...but again, that's a bit silly. :-)

Answer (score 1):

use replace method

```js
var str = "Javascript";
str = str.replace("v", "");
alert(str);
```